# Why would callbacks be used in this API design pattern?

Tags: python

I have been using an API package made for algotrading on a specific site, while I have been using it I have found some of the design patterns used quite confusing and have left me asking questions WHY they have done it this way, here is what I am working with:

```
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        super().openOrder(orderId, contract, order, orderState)
        print(order) 


app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)
app.reqAllOpenOrders() #This triggers the above openOrder method as per their design pattern via a callback
```

I have this class IBApi which inherits the parent classes EWrapper and EClient so I can now access any methods within these two classes using the `super()` notation. If I want to access say my current open orders the docs say to call the method `app.reqAllOpenOrders` which then triggers a call back executing the `openOrder` method that I have overwritten in my IBApi class meaning I can tap into this and get my data.

Now this kinda makes sense to me logically speaking however what Im questioning is WHY is this design pattern used? Is there a specific reason to this and any reason why they just havent had a more linnear means where you can just call say some method `app.getOrders` which returns a list of all the data I need and doesnt use a callback?

Comment: It looks like `reqAllOpenOrders` just happens to call `openOrder` in its definition, which is simply an internal function call and not technically a callback routine. You, of course, can override the definition of the inherited `openOrder` method and do what you will. Nothing crazy is happening here.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I think Im just over thinking it, strange thing is that nearly all of their built in methods you can call on the `app` object require you to override some other parent method to get the data, rather than just calling say arbitrary app.getData and being returned a physical object/list

Comment: It sounds like they are implementing some sort of Interface design pattern, which isn't really supported in Python by default, so you have to do some funny stuff to simulate it. Basically any class inheriting `EWrapper` or `EClient` must provide a definition for certain methods, for example.